# R rugarch package. Error: parameters names do not match specification

Tags: r, time-series

I'm working on a personal project in R with the aim of fitting some GARCH models to returns which are then used to estimate some risk measures on univariate financial time series.
To fit the univariate GARCH models I'm using the package 'rugarch'.
Now, I set-up a gjrGarch model with `garchOrder=c(3,3)` and `armaOrder=c(3,3)` in the ugarchspec and then, with ugarchfit I fitted the model. However, when it comes to get the forecasted values of mu and sigma with `ugarchforecast` I get the following error:

```
ugarchfilter-->error: parameters names do not match specification
Expected Parameters are: mu ar1 ar2 ar3 ma1 ma2 ma3 omega alpha1 alpha2 alpha3 beta1 beta2 beta3 gamma1 gamma2 gamma3
Error: Exiting
```

Does anybody know what it means and how to solve it?
This is the code I wrote:

```
for (i in 1:length(df_data_wd_15$Return))
{
  model=ugarchspec(variance.model=list(model='gjrGARCH', garchOrder=c(3,3)), mean.model=list(armaOrder=c(3,3), include.mean=TRUE), distribution.model='norm')
  modelfit=ugarchfit(spec=model, data=df_data_wd_15$Return[i:(i+199)])

  foref<-ugarchforecast(modelfit, n.ahead=2)

  mu_for[i]<-foref@forecast$seriesFor[1]
  sigma_for[i]<-foref@forecast$sigmaFor[1]
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A) Unfortunately, I can only help you with what the error means.

As the error messages states, `modelfit` doesn't contain the expected parameters, such that the forecast cannot be calculated. This could be the case when **the solver in `modelfit` wasn't able to find a solution** and fit coefficients.

You could check whether this is the case by printing `modelfit` and checking whether it looks empty. You could also double-check if that is truly where to problem lies by typing `traceback()` into your command prompt, which would show you in which line the error occurred.

B) How to solve the problem, or why the solver couldn't find a solution, I don't know. I suggest for you to (i) have a look at the specifications, to see whether there is something at odds there, or (ii) play around with the `solver` and`solver.control`  options (see documentation for  `ugarchfit`), e.g. to allow multiple restarts.